# [React-Native]Is there any way setting path alias like webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webpack

For example, I can set `config.resolve.alias.MODELS = path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'models')` in webpack configuration, so I can `import MyModel from 'MODELS/MyModel';`. Is there any way I can accomplish this in **React-Native**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what I want - [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver)